# JavaFX FilteredList Generics getPredicate()

Tags: java, generics, javafx

I have just encountered an impossible generic method. It seems I can't write a method that takes a JavaFX filtered list and a predicated and simply ands the filtered list predicate with the passed in predicate. The only way is to either cast which in certain cases will result in a `ClassCastException` or to use Raw types. I don't think java can represent `<? super <? super String>>`. Can anyone spot if I have missed anything out?

```
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
public class Test {
  void and(FilteredList<String> l, Predicate<? super String> predicate) { //Impossible generics on 2nd parameter
    l.getPredicate().and(predicate);
  }
}
```

Using `Predicate<? super Object>` doesn't work because it isn't generic enough:

```
public class Test {
  <T> Predicate<? super T> and(FilteredList<T> l, Predicate<? super Object> predicate) {
      return l.getPredicate().and(predicate);
  }

  public void exampleCall(FilteredList<Integer> integers, Predicate<Number> numberPredicate) {
     return and(integers, numberPredicate); // doesn't compile
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
void and(FilteredList<String> l, Predicate<? super Object> predicate) { 
    l.getPredicate().and(predicate);
}
```

This is pretty much the only thing that makes sense anyway. The predicate on a `FilteredList<String>` has type `Predicate<? super String>`, which makes sense, because it would be perfectly valid to use a `Predicate<Object>` there. So (if you excuse the slight abuse of syntax) `FilteredList<String>.getPredicate()` returns a predicate that can be applied to some unknown (but specific) supertype of `String`.

The requirement for the parameter passed to the `and()` method for a `Predicate<T>` is that it must be able to test an object of type `T`, so it makes sense for that to be a `Predicate<? super T>`.

Thus the type passed to `l.getPredicate().and(...)` must be a predicate that can be applied to a `? super String`, i.e. that can be applied to some unknown supertype of `String`: the most specific such type is `? super Object`.

(Throughout, I am using the convention used in the generics jargon that a type `T` is considered to be a supertype of itself, so by "supertype of `T`" I mean "`T` or one of its superclasses", etc.)

Note that the resulting expression has type `Predicate<? super String>`, so you can do

```
Predicate<? super String> and(FilteredList<String> l, Predicate<? super Object> predicate) {
    return l.getPredicate().and(predicate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks James, Thats a good suggestion however the method isn't as generic as it could be. Here is an example call I would like to make:
    public class Test {
      <T> Predicate<? super T> and(FilteredList<T> l, Predicate<? super Object> predicate) {
        return l.getPredicate().and(predicate);
      }

      public void exampleCall(FilteredList<Integer> integers, Predicate<Number> numberPredicate) {
        return and(integers, numberPredicate); // doesn't compile
      }   
    }</code>

Comment: @NikolayMetchev Can you edit your question with that? It's hard to read the code in a comment.